# how do i add a curved dotted line around 3 divs one below other as attached in the image

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do i add a curved dotted line around 3 divs as attached in the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that

```css
.content{width: 400px;position: relative;}
.round-dot1 {
  border: 2px dotted #000000; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;  
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #000000;
  border-right: 0px dotted #000000;

  float: left;

  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
.round-dot2 {
  border: 2px dotted #000000;
  border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 0px dotted #000000;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div >
      <div class="round-dot1">
      Here are some text Here are some text <br /><br />Here are some text <br /><br />Another text
      </div>
  </div>
  <div >
      <div class="round-dot2">
      Here are some text Here are some text <br /><br />Here are some text <br /><br />Another text
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8netg8j/5/).

That is only the begin of whole solution.

Tip:
Next time, please send more details in your question and also attach your code.